# Can't Move the Dropbox Folder to Ext4 or NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, encryption, dropbox, file-format

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. In response to the change in dropbox file system support, I created a new partition on my hard drive to store my dropbox files in. It's 2 GB larger than my maximum dropbox space.

My main partitions are all Ext4, but my home partition is encrypted which apparently doesn't work. This new partition was made without any obvious encryption option.

Trying to move the dropbox folder, using dropbox > preferences > sync > dropbox folder location, and selecting a folder on my new partition returns a system incompatability error (see screenshot)

I reformatted the partition to NTFS, but dropbox refuses to move the folder, with the same vague error. I looked through the circuitous FAQs this error links to, as far as I can see there's no other special circumstances to my setup.  I'm just a guy using linux who doesn't want to reinstall his entire OS, and is about ready to cancel his dropbox subscirption.

[Dropbox Cannot Move Folder Location Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7ipc.png)

[Proof of NTFS partition format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpA1V.png)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Error-messages/Ubuntu-16-04-Error-moving-files-to-new-ext4-location/m-p/304087#M17994

Basically, use a subfolder of the new ext4 partition as target for dropbox. It worked for me.

Comment: The subfolder allows me to select the folder (instead of it being outright rejected). But then it says "Unexpected errors occurred. Your Dropbox is ok!" What a cluster.